# Move asp.net gridview rows up and down with button click with sorting enabled

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to move the gridview rows up and down with button click and i followed this

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/06/move-aspnet-gridview-rows-up-and-down.html

and it is working fine. However, I have sorting enabled on my gridview. The rows does not move up and down when the column is sorted. Can someone suggest how to implement it so that the gridview rows are moved up and down even when the column is sorted.

Thanks,

Comment: can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

This is another method to move rows UP and Down in grid view.

```
if (e.CommandName == "UP")
        {
        Button btnup = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnup.NamingContainer;
        var rows = id.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(a => a != row).ToList();
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "UP":
                if (row.RowIndex.Equals(0))
                    rows.Add(row);
                else
                    rows.Insert(row.RowIndex - 1, row);
                break;
            case "Down":
                if (row.RowIndex.Equals(id.Rows.Count - 1))
                    rows.Insert(0, row);
                else
                    rows.Insert(row.RowIndex + 1, row);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Old Post but not enough rep to comment, Pratiks answer will only fire the UP command because the Down command is built within the first if statement... it needs to be.

```
Button btnup = (Button)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnup.NamingContainer;
var rows = id.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(a => a != row).ToList();
if (e.CommandName == "UP")
    {
            if (row.RowIndex.Equals(0)) {
                rows.Add(row);}
            else {
                rows.Insert(row.RowIndex - 1, row); }
    }
}
else if (e.CommandName == "DOWN")
{
            if (row.RowIndex.Equals(id.Rows.Count - 1)) {
                rows.Insert(0, row);}
            else {
                rows.Insert(row.RowIndex + 1, row);}
}
```